# Pandas Create Data Frame Column from List

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given the following list:

```
list=['a','b','c']
```

I'd like to create a data frame where the list is the column of values.
I'd like the header to be "header".

Like this:

```
header
a
b
c
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do note that `list` is [a built-in type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) so you should most likely name your variable to something else :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wouldn't that be:

```
list=['a','b','c']
df= pd.DataFrame({'header': list})


  header
0      a
1      b
2      c
```

Comment: Yes; I spaced out on that one for sure.